# How to keep adding ints into a list and meanwhile looking if those ints arent already in the list?

Tags: c#, .net, list, for-loop

I want to make a list of ints of users input. But when this list already has the int which the user fills in, it has to give an `error` (Console.Writeline). This is what I have so far:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();

//this code is in a for-loop 
string a = console.ReadLine();
if(!int.TryParse(a, out number))
   Console.WriteLine("give a number");
else
{
    if (number < anotherlist.Count && number >= 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (list[i] == number)
                Console.WriteLine("number already given");//so dont add this number to the list
            else
                list.Add(number);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (list.Contains(number))` ?

Comment: So what is it that you need? What does `number < anotherlist.Count` intend to compare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a nested `for`-loop you could simplify your code by using [`List.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
bool alreadyContained = list.Contains(number);
if(alreadyContained)
    Console.WriteLine("number already given");
else
    list.Add(number);
```

However, i don't understand why you need this `if`:

```
if (number < anotherlist.Count && number >= 0)
```

Why does the number have to be in the range of 0 and anotherlist.Count?

Comment: Thank you Tim for this answer, gonna try this out directly. The `if (number < anotherlist.Count && number >= 0)` is to check is the number given is between the count of an another list, because I want a user to select which strings will be selected out of the other list (anotherlist)

Comment: So I got a list with strings, I display them all, and let the user decide which string may `pass`, if the user chooses number 2 and 4, the anotherlist[3] and anotherlist[5] will be put into a new list, to use this

Answer (score 6):

You can use [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). HashSet is optimized for storing set of values.

```
var ints = new HashSet<int>(); // creating HashSet

ints.Add(1); // adding items to HashSet

if (ints.Contains(1)) // check if HashSet already has the value
{
    Console.WriteLine("number already exist");
}

if (!ints.Add(1)) // check if the added value already exists
{
    Console.WriteLine("number already exist");
}

var list = ints.ToList(); //converting HashSet to List
```

Comment: Yes, he can. But it's not necessary unless the list is not really large.

Comment: Do you need the `Contains()`? If the int is present in the set then it wont get added again..

Comment: @dotctor You can do `if(!ints.Add(number))` to determine if the number is already in the hash set and add it at the same time if it isn't.

Comment: thats whay i was getting at @juharr. `Add` returns a `boolean` so can check that way

Answer (score 2):

I recommend doing a few things:

- Catch exceptions after throwing new ones when you encounter bad data.
- Provide a method for printing the list.
- Provide an exit.
- Provide an "event loop". This checks to see if you want to keep going.
- Optionally replace the list with a hashset. Since your requirement stated a list, I didn't do that.

  ```
  using System;

  using System.Collections.Generic;

  namespace NumberListExample
  {
      class Program
      {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
              List<int> list = new List<int>();
              string userInput = string.Empty;
              int number;
          Console.WriteLine("Type numbers and hit enter to add to list.\n"
              +"Do not repeat numbers.\nTo stop, type 'exit'. To print the list, type 'print'.");
          do
          {
              Console.Write("Enter a whole number: ");
              try //Throw exceptions to be handled later.
              {
                  userInput = Console.ReadLine(); //Read in user input

              if (userInput.ToUpper() == "PRINT") //if the user desires to print...
              {
                  PrintList(list);
              }
              else //If the user hasn't requested a print...
              {
                  if (int.TryParse(userInput, out number))
                  {
                      //if the list doesn't contain this value
                      if (!list.Contains(number))
                      {
                          //add to the list
                          list.Add(number);
                      }
                      else //the list contains the value
                      {
                          //Throw a new exception specifying the problem
                          throw new Exception(string.Format("This list already contains {0}!", number));
                      }
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      throw new Exception("This is not a whole number.");
                  }
              }
          }
          catch (NullReferenceException ex)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Cannot accept null values!");
          }
          catch (Exception ex) //Print the exception message.
          {
              //Print the message of the exception thrown:
              Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
          }

        //Accept all casing by first converting input to uppercase.
      } while (userInput.ToUpper() != "EXIT");


  }

  private static void PrintList(IEnumerable<int> list)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("List of numbers:");
      foreach (int number in list)
      {
          Console.Write("{0}, ", number);
      }
      //Skip a line:
      Console.WriteLine();
  }
  }
  }
  ```